# Run same coordinator with different input values

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a coordinator which I'd like to run with different input values.
For example, below are the 'input-events' provided. I would like to run the coordinator job with the following values of param 'benzene_hbase_input_offset':

1. (-24) - looks at the data of the last 24 hours.
2. (-96) - looks at the data of the last 96 hours.

Nowadays I run only option '2'. In order to avoid code duplication, I'd like to run the same coordinator with a different input for the 'start-instance' param.
How can I do that?

```
<input-events>
    <data-in name="benzene_dwell_calc-output" dataset="BENZENE_DWELL_CALC_OUTPUT">
        <start-instance>${coord:current(benzene_hbase_input_offset)}</start-instance>
        <end-instance>${coord:current(-1)}</end-instance>
    </data-in>
    <data-in name="benzene_dwell_calc-output" dataset="BENZENE_DWELL_CALC_OUTPUT">
        <start-instance>${coord:current(benzene_hbase_input_offset)}</start-instance>
        <end-instance>${coord:current(-1)}</end-instance>
    </data-in>
</input-events>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this param in the jog.properties.
In the coordinator place it in the start instance and also place it in the coordinator name so you can distinct between the two

Comment: Mzf - thanks for the answer.

Is there a way to create an inheritance in the coordinator level? for example - create a "common" coordinator, for which I'll create two instances that will inherit from the 'common' one, but we will add small modifications into it.

Comment: what other changes do you have ? if the only change is just changing the time windows - I think the above answer the question. There is an option to include, for example the datasets

Comment: I'd like to inherit everything in the coordinator xml, and only change about three things:
1. coord name
2. datasets
3. input-events

Comment: You can only include the datasets. The coordinator name you can set it from the configure file. For the input event - if you want to change the start/end instance, same like the coordinator name.